# A more concise Finite Automata for 10 substring?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions, computation-models, substrings

I am learning about finite automata and trying to create a machine that matches

**`{w ∈ Σ∗| w does not contain the substring 10}`**

I created a DFA where it either starts with `1` or `0`. I know it's not the most concise FA, but is it accurate?[image]

Comment: Hello , your diagram seems to be incomplete, the initial state isn't indicated.
Also, and this might be some convention I'm simply not aware of, but the transitions in a FSA usually only contain one character.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1331/755

Answer (score 4):

Your automat**on** (automata is the plural word) is wrong:

- as @Knogger stated, there is no initial state
- finite automata (unless generalized) can only have one-letter transitions, so transitions $01$ are not allowed
- even if $01$ transitions are allowed, this would create $10$ as substring, since $0101$ contains $10$.

You should try again, noting the fact that a word $w\in \{0,1\}^*$ does not contain $10$ as a substring if and only if $w = 0^p1^q$, for some $p, q\geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This one is a classic textbook problem. You can build your required DFA as follows:

step 1: build a complete DFA $M$ that accepts all strings containing `10` as a substring

step 2: just swap the status of final/non-final states in this DFA to get another DFA $M'$

step 3: argue that $M'$ has to be your required one

Read more about DFA complementation [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/151344/).